# Ordercloud: Invalid Client Error when using Postman OR .NET SDK

Tags: ordercloud

currently I am trying to test some stuff with Ordercloud.
Therefore I created a Sandbox account and tried now to use the API Clients to connect some app to it. But all the time I am trying to create some client it fails with 400 invalid_client.
I already tried all kinds of variants like, with username & password or with client_secret.[image]

Same output as in Postman, but with .NET SDK
[image]
[image]

From what I can see, the client is there and the id and secret should be fine
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using sandbox environment, you should define the ApiUrl and AuthUrl Properties too to point them to the sandbox url. (By default, they points to the live environments)

```
 var client = new OrderCloud.SDK.OrderCloudClient(new OrderCloud.SDK.OrderCloudClientConfig
    {
        ClientId = "<your client id>",

        // client credentials grant flow:
       ClientSecret = "<your client secret>",

       
        ApiUrl = "https://sandboxapi.ordercloud.io",

        Roles = new[] { OrderCloud.SDK.ApiRole.ProductAdmin },
        AuthUrl = "https://sandboxapi.ordercloud.io/"
    } );
```

Comment: Good point  Did not read that in sdk doku